# I am getting error related to return issubclass(cls, self.__origin__) TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class

Tags: python

```
def __subclasscheck__(self, cls):
    
    if isinstance(cls, _SpecialGenericAlias):
        return issubclass(cls.__origin__, self.__origin__)
    if not isinstance(cls, _GenericAlias):
        return issubclass(cls, self.__origin__)
    return super().__subclasscheck__(cls)
```

TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class

Comment: Did you check if cls is a class? How was class instanciated?

Comment: The fact that `isinstance` and `issubclass` are both being used for the same object, suggests this implementation is flawed. Generally, `cls` will be a class instance, or a class by itself; not both.